# How to proper blend two imageview using ScriptIntrinsicBlend

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript

this is my current implementation which output different as expected

```
     private fun multiplyBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap?):Bitmap{
         var mRenderScript = RenderScript.create(context!!)
         var bitmapMultiply = mOriginalBitmap!!.copy(mOriginalBitmap!!.config,true)
         var blend = ScriptIntrinsicBlend.create(mRenderScript, U8_4(mRenderScript))
         var allocationIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRenderScript, originalBackground)
         var allocationOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRenderScript,bitmapMultiply)

         blend.forEachMultiply(allocationIn,allocationOut)

         return bitmapMultiply
}
```

Comment: Each of the src/dst methods in `ScriptIntrinsicBlend` maps to a [Porter-Duff mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode) If you are really trying to multiply two images, you should update your post with details as to what your inputs are and what your expected output should be.

Comment: Any success getting this working? I'm trying a few things similar to this and nothing happens...

Comment: @slott, ScriptIntrinsicBlend did not work for me. I just use PorterDuff

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a crucial part. It should call `allocationOut.copyTo(bitmapMultiply)` after the call to `forEachMultiply`.

The `copyTo` call ensures that the data is completely copied from GPU memory to the data store backing the bitmap.